# How to restore SQL localDB programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, restore, localdb

I'm trying to create backup and restore functionality to my Windows form application.

So, I've tried to do a database restore. My code is like this:

```
string cbdfilename = "c:\\Users\\Public\\Public Document";
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
string sql;

sql = "Use master;Alter Database BbCon Set Single_User With Rollback Immediate;Restore Database BbCon From Disk = @FILENAME With Replace;Alter Database BbCon Set Multi_User;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME", cbdfilename);

con.Open();

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Restore DB failed" + ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

But when I try to run this, I get an error:

> Restore db failed System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0X80131904):userdoesnot have permission to alter database BbCon.mdf the database doesnot exist or or datbase is not in a state that allows access checks.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It's a local DB, just disconnect from it and copy the file with System.IO commands like FileStream.  Then to restore it just overwrite the MDB with a copy of the backup.

I don't believe local db mdb files have system/master tables etc or that backup/restore commands will work on them.

Comment: @Ryan Mann, localDB is MDF and also has standard backup/restore command. But some part is correct, when we need just a copy of MDF, (not backup), we're needed need to stop Server and just copy..

Comment: And 'ALTER DATABASE' requires to connect to Master Database as administrator (Integrated Security=True). Then the exception message with permissions will be solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying to Backup or Restore? You mention Backup in the Title and the commmand is for Restore.

There're not many example cases for localDB yet.

Utilize my code as below. Hope this helps..

For Backup-

```
string master_ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";

using (SqlConnection masterdbConn = new SqlConnection())
{
     masterdbConn.ConnectionString = master_ConnectionString;
     masterdbConn.Open();

     using (SqlCommand multiuser_rollback_dbcomm = new SqlCommand())
     {
         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.Connection = masterdbConn;
         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.CommandText= @"ALTER DATABASE yourdbname SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";

         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     masterdbConn.Close();
}

SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

using (SqlConnection backupConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    backupConn.ConnectionString = yourConnectionString;
    backupConn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand backupcomm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        backupcomm.Connection = backupConn;
        backupcomm.CommandText= @"BACKUP DATABASE yourdbname TO DISK='c:\yourdbname.bak'";
        backupcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    backupConn.Close();
}
```

For Restore-

```
string master_ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";

using (SqlConnection restoreConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    restoreConn.ConnectionString = master_ConnectionString;
    restoreConn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand restoredb_executioncomm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        restoredb_executioncomm.Connection = restoreConn;
        restoredb_executioncomm.CommandText = @"RESTORE DATABASE yourdbname FROM DISK='c:\yourdbname.bak'";

        restoredb_executioncomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    restoreConn.Close();
}
```

Update-

Oops, sorry, my code is for SQL localDB 2014 but it seems you're using 2012.
Kindly replace (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB to (LocalDB)\v11.0

And kindly just try with above change.

And for your information, as per my experience, if I wrote |Data Directory| in my connectionString, I could only read (SQL SELECT command) the Database. In other word to say, the Insert and Update commands could be done but the database was not inserted or updated actually without any exception. I think setting as |Data Directory| would make the database as read-only and I've found some people were having difficulties to insert or update to database with |Data Directory| setting.

Hope your good days ! Thanks !

Comment: thanks for the code but when i tried the code above i getting an error error-50 database runtime error provided database instance name is  invalid can you please help me

Comment: the backup was restored but after i published and used in clients system i get an error database is in used cant be restored

Comment: Before restoration, try 'ALTER DATABASE ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE' as I showed in Backup code.This finishes all the un-finished transactions finished just like 'hands off from the DB before we backup'. In other word to say, Before we close a restaurant, if we don't announce that this restaurant is going to be closed, if we suddenly close the restaurant, some customers might remain still having foods eventhough the restaurant is closing.And about |Data Directory| refer to my answer to another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322388/backup-localdb-database-in-clickonce/42324032#42324032

Comment: ALTER DATABASE ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE plays such role.